# Image capturing continuously

Tags: initialization

I am a final year student making a project in which I take a image from camera placed at car and my objective is through image processing on Matlab. I have to take image of different colour ball until my desired image (which is red) comes and the car stop through micro controller. How can I continuously take a image of ball with millisecond time delay?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to capture one image each millisecond? That requires a 1000 Hz camera, and those are *expensive*.

Answer (score 0):

The [For-A VFC-1000SB High Speed](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/554003-REG/For_A_VFC_1000SB_VFC_1000SB_High_Speed_Variable.html) -- only about $12k :-)

However, on the "cheap" end there is the Exilim line (e.g. [EX-F1](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/reviews/casio-exf1.shtml)). One of the features is a [movie mode up to 1200fps](http://www.exilim.com/intl/ex_f1/features2.html). Note that as the fps goes up the resolution goes down. I know nothing more about this other than the adverting. YMMV.

Now, even if the *camera* can take frames at this speed, getting it to the host and processed "somewhat timely" is unlikely without additional specialty hardware (and I doubt it is doable at all with the Exilim).